# How to create a blank excel file using C# forms?

Tags: c#, excel

I can't seem to create a new blank excel file so I can write in it with excel Interop later

```
 System.IO.FileStream fs =(System.IO.FileStream)saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
 switch (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex)
 {
     case 1:
         //write blank xlsx?
         break;
     case 2:
         //write blank xls?
         break;
 }
 fs.Close();
 ExportDataSetToExcel(_destinationDataSet, saveFileDialog1.FileName);
```

If I pass an empty file I got this error

> Cant open file because the file format or file extension is not valid.
>   Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file
>   extension matches the format of the file.

So.. How can I create an empty xls or xls file?

Comment: If you're planning on using Excel Interop why don't you create the workbook and save that?

Comment: First, check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.openfile(v=vs.110).aspx) to validate that you are correctly using `SaveFileDialog` (did you open the dialog, so that a filename could be selected?)

Comment: @rene Although i honestly dont know how to do that, I wish to be free from Excel Interop as possible... It is super slow and requires clients to have a full office suite to work

Comment: Yes the file name is created successfully and a blank 0 bytes file is created @Alexei

Comment: Use the OpenXML sdk, ClosedXml or EPPlus ...

Comment: Why not simply have an empty copy of each type of file available and make a copy of the template file?

Comment: I have picked Open Xml @rene.

Comment: Too late man, very late.. only if you were here 20 minutes sooner @LasseV.Karlsen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way

```
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
var wb = app.Workbooks.Add();
wb.SaveAs("File Path.xlsx");
wb.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Empty Excel files are not simple empty files, since they also store some header data. One modern way of writing Excel files is to use `Open XML SDK 2.5` as indicated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478153.aspx):

```
var spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
```

By doing so, you get a reference that allows you to write data to the Excel file.

In order to get a value for `filepath`, you can you use `SaveFileDialog` to indicate path to be used like indicated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files|*.xlsx";
saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Image File";
saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

if(saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
{
    // file name is available here
}
```

You can make your Excel manipulation in C# even easier by using a third party library such as [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

**Disclaimer:** Above hints work only for the Excel 2007 and above formats.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this...

```
if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
    {
      var app = new Application();
      var wb = app.Workbooks.Add();
      switch (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex)
         {
            case 1:
               wb.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
               break;    
            case 2:
               wb.SaveAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName, XlFileFormat.xlExcel8);
                        break;
         }
      wb.Close();
      app.Quit();

      ExportDataSetToExcel(_destinationDataSet, saveFileDialog1.FileName);
    }
```